# Wordpress: Query events

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I would like to create a query for a custom post type 'events' and - of course - display the upcoming events. I would like to create a 'Query-ID' to handle the query via Elementor's 'Posts' widget.

I've added this code to my functions.php

```
$current_date_query = date ('d.m.Y H:i'); //date format selected in ACF
add_action('elementor/query/kls-event-liste', function($query){ 
$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
$query->set('meta_key', 'event_start');
$query->set('type', 'DATETIME');
$query->set('meta_value', '$current_date_query');
$query->set('meta_compare', '>');
$query->set('order', 'ASC');});
```

I can select the Query-ID 'kls-event-liste' in Elementor and for example change the order by setting it to DESC. But still ALL events are shown - past and upcoming.

What may I do?

Thanks,
Nico